# MVC Controller implementing an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

Has anybody managed to do the following in MVC 4 with Castle windsor?  I'm currently experimenting after watching a video about Hexagonal Architecture & trying to be more Domain driven - i.e. concentrate on the messages between objects.

```
public class UserController : Controller, ICreatedUser
{
   public IUserCreator _creator;

   public class UserController(IUserCreator creator)
   {
      _creator = creator;
   }

   public void Create(CreateUserModel model)
   {
      _creator.Create(model);
   }

   public ViewResult Successful(User user)
   {
       return View(user);
   }

   public ViewResult Unsuccessful()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
public interface ICreatedUser
{
   ViewResult Successful(User user);
   ViewResult Unsuccessful();
}

public class UserCreator : IUserCreator
{
  private ICreatedUser _createdUser;

  public class UserCreator(ICreatedUser createdUser)  // I want the controller injected here
  {
      _createdUser = createdUser;
  }
}
```

I know that one of the problems is that the "ViewResult" on the ICreatedUser is too specific to the UI - probably a limitation of C#.

Comment: Am I seeing this right? You want UserController to be injected into the ctor of UserCreator, although the ctor of UserController needs in turn an already existing instance of IUserCreator(so maybe UserCreator?) ?

Comment: And how should the container handle that circular reference? If the UserCreator needs a controller, which needs the user creator first, which needs a controller, which... chicken and egg?

Comment: I can do this without a container, just seems I'll have to new up some of my dependencies on the fly.